# Não limpar os dados da tela ao dar erro

Tags: javascript, ajax

Olá, sou um pouco leigo com `scripts` ainda. Peço uma ajuda, se for possível.

Tenho o seguinte `script` :

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/PreVenda/GuardarPreVenda",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(json),
                    async: false,//this makes the ajax-call blocking
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',

                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                        window.location.reload().ajax();
                        valid = response.valid;
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert(error);

                    }
                });

            });
```

Uso o `window.location.reload().ajax();` para quando salvar, ele limpe todos os campos da tela, mas quando ocorre um erro na página, ele simplesmente limpa os campos também, eu só quero que limpe os campos, quando ocorre tudo certo e não quando der erros.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Como estás a chamar esse `$.ajax`?  Não terás uma `<form>` ou  `<a>` que está a ser chamado? O que é esse `...reload().ajax()`?

Comment: Esse reload().ajax() está estranho mesmo.

Comment: Eu chamo o ajax toda vez que clico no botão salvar, eu não tenho um <form> ou <a> para ser chamado, esse reload().ajax() faz que todo o meu formulário limpe, mas ela limpa ate quando da erro, queria algum jeito de só limpar se de tudo certo.

Comment: Me parece que após o `success`, ele quer dar um reload na página. Mas aí não faz sentido dar um reload usando Ajax.

Comment: eu tentei usar depois do `success` chamar a function
`  function limpiar() {
            $("id_cliente").val("");
            $("nome_cliente").val("");
            $("id_vendedor").val("");
            $("nome_vendedor").val("");
            $("Tot_bruto").val("");
            $("Tot_desc_prc").val("");
        }`

`Limpar()`, mas não limpa.

Comment: @Alyssonbormann Pode dar um exemplo de qual erro pode aparecer que tambem limpa os campos?

Comment: Da erro caso o usuário não informe um nome, ou id, validação básica mesmo, que esta sendo tratada dentro do meu código e não por script

Comment: Faltou colocar # ->> `$("#id_cliente").val("");` em cada um dos seletores.

Answer (score 2):

Você está usando `window.location.reload()` apenas para limpar os campos do formulário e isso não é absolutamente recomendado.

Digamos que o seu formulário seja `<form id="form">`, faça então um seletor no identificador do formulário e execute:

```
success: function (response) {
    $("#form")[0].reset();
    valid = response.valid;
}
```

Ou, no caso de limpar o formulário esteja atrelado à validade da resposta:

```
success: function (response) {
    valid = response.valid;

    if (valid){
        $("#form")[0].reset();
   };
}
```

Ou como javascript puro (sugestão no comentário):

```
success: function (response) {
    valid = response.valid;

    if (valid){
        document.getElementById("form").reset();
   };
}
```

Lembre-se de trocar **`#form`** pelo identificador do seu formulário que melhor lhe convier.

Comment: Ou então em JS puro: `document.getElementById("form").reset();`

Comment: Certamente. Editei.